# How to delete selected item on python treeview from the mysql table?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to delete a selected record from treeview and from the database Mysql at the same time. The insertion of the records from the database to treeview and the deletion of a selected record from treeview worked.

But my question is how to delete the selected record from database also?

```
tv=ttk.Treeview(manage,columns=(1,2,3,4,5),show="headings",height="25")


    tv.insert('','end',values=i)
```

Comment: Did you print out the value of `val` to see whether it is the expected `id` in the table?

Comment: It is better to post the code on how you populate the records into the treeview.

Comment: i will upload the code so you can get a full understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest to set the `iid` option to the `ID` from the table:

```py
for i in rows:
    tv.insert('', 'end', iid=i[0], values=i) # assume ID is the first column in the table
```

Then you can delete the record from table inside `removeRecord()` as below:

```py
def removeRecord():
    selected = tv.selection()
    if selected:
        # a row is selected
        x = selected[0]
        tv.delete(x)
        # delete record from table
        sql = 'DELETE FROM employeeInfo WHERE ID = %s'
        mycursor.execute(sql, (x,))
        # assume mydb is the connection object of MySQL database
        mydb.commit()  # make sure to commit the change
```